# MDX MEDIAN() Function Incorrect Results

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to implement a data cube whereby I can show the average and the median of a measure for a given set of dimensions. Basic example using AdventureWorksDW:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Median Qty] AS
     MEDIAN ( [Product].[Product Categories].siblings, [Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity])
    MEMBER [Measures].[avgOrderSize] AS
    CASE
        WHEN [Measures].[Reseller Sales Count] = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE ([Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity]  / [Measures].[Reseller Sales Count])
    END

SELECT {[Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity], [Measures].[Median Qty], [Measures].[avgOrderSize]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY([Product].[Product Categories].[Category]) ON 1
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
WHERE ([Product].[Product Name].&[476]);
```

The output is:

[image: Median output]

My `[Measures].[avgOrderSize]` is correct as it appears to be using the actual measures returned in the query. However, the `[Measures].[Median Qty]` is not at all correct for what my requirements are. I would have though the value would be around 6 (given that my AdventureWorksDW2012 has 344 reseller orders that include this product). It looks like the MEDIAN() is working across the entire set of products?

I have tried variations on `[Product].[Product Categories].siblings` including `[Product].[Product Name].CurrentMember` which returned the identical value as the Reseller Sales-Order Quantity
What am I doing wrong and how can I get the MEDIAN() function to act like I am expecting?

Comment: Do you have a degenerate dimension that has one dimension member for every reseller order (in your real cube I mean)? What version of SSAS and is it Enterprise edition?

Comment: @GregGalloway We do have degenerate dimensions in our real data. I am hoping to understand MEDIAN in the AW data first so I have something to test and compare with. We are using SSAS 2012 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning. This will be slow. But it should be correct. I'm afraid Median is just an expensive calculation. The first parameter should be a degenerate dimension and an attribute which has one member per row in the fact table.

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Median Qty] AS
     MEDIAN ( EXISTING [Reseller Sales].[Reseller Sales Order Number].[Reseller Sales Order Number].Members, [Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity])
    ...
```

Comment: I modified this a bit to work with my version of the AW dimensions. And it seems to return expected results. Marking this as the answer. However, this will not work in our live OLAP our degenerate dimension fails to build due to 4GB files size limit (that was a neat error). It seems we will be unable to show percentiles when using OLAP.

Comment: @wergeld there is a setting to allow larger dimensions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471589(SQL.110).aspx but I suspect MEDIAN over that size dimension is pointlessly slow.

Comment: @GregGalloway how come this didn't work? `EXISTING [Product].[Product Categories].siblings` (I don't have this test cube - it is different from the AdvWrks I have access to)

Comment: Yea, this would most likely be non-functional even if we can get the DBAs to increase size limits.We wouldn't be calculating the MEDIAN across the entire data set - we force selection of time, location, and other parameters to narrow the resulting data set.

Comment: The `siblings` just returned the same value as the "Reseller Sales-Order Quantity" which was 2,881. The expected value was 6.

Comment: @whytheq it gave you the median of the product subcategory subtotals. The questioner wanted the row level median

Answer (score 0):

I've not played with that function yet but a couple of things you could try are:

Add the `EXISTING` keyword to the calculation:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Median Qty] AS
     MEDIAN ( 
        EXISTING [Product].[Product Categories].siblings
      , [Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity]
     )
...
```

Add the `Exists` function although this is probably very similar to the above:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Median Qty] AS
     MEDIAN ( 
        EXISTS([Product].[Product Categories].siblings, [Product].[Product Name].&[476])
      , [Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity]
     )
...
```

Try this:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Median Qty] AS
     MEDIAN ( 
        [Product].[Product Categories].currentmember.siblings
      , [Measures].[Reseller Sales-Order Quantity]
     )
...
```

Comment: I tried both `EXISTING` and `EXISTS` and this just returns the same value as "Reseller Sales-Order Quantity" which is 2881 (for this product). It looks like this just does the MEDIAN across the set that contains the product (good) but only at the aggregate level (bad) so MEDIAN is only calculated for the single value of the Quantity totaled.

Comment: @wergeld I added a third attempt! this is from viewing the example in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145570.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This returns the same value as my initial query - 1030.5. I have to be missing something simple - I just don't know what it is yet.